# Template for technical report (with sections, without chapters)?

Tags: templates

I need to prepare a technical report (using win7 and TeXnicCenter) and it is around 50 pages (table of content + text + image + formulas + tables + etc.). The report should not have chapters, only sections. So I have used the `article` document class.

I'm wondering if anybody could recommend an elegant formal template which does not have chapters, but is good for a technical report (not just an article). I found some nice templates on [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/) but they seem more fit for a journal article.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: The article class is flexible enough for a technical report. I'd say go for it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This is for a course and the instructor has specifically mentioned that the report should not have chapters. The article class works fine, but if you know some free template I can download with more visually pleasing! formatting, let me know.